# Is there a way to suppress Growl notifications when all the specs pass in guard-rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, guard, growl

Is it possible to suppress guard-rspec notifications when all the specs pass? I'd like to get a giant Growl notification when the specs fail, though. Is that possible?

i.e. Does such a setting exist in any part of the stack?

1. [guard-rspec](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec)
2. [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard)
3. [the growl gem](https://github.com/visionmedia/growl)
4. [growlnotify](http://growl.info/extras.php#growlnotify) command line app
5. [growl](http://growl.info/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my version of Growl - the paid version from the Mac App store - which I use with the `gntp` gem I am able to configure a `Guard` option under the `Applications` tab in the Growl settings.

Here you can enable or disable growl notifications for success or failure separately.

There is one implication, if you disable success then you get the following line at the end of your test run where there were no errors:

```
ERROR: Error sending notification with gntp: Notify failed
```

For failures you will get a notification as expected.

Comment: Where exactly can I do this? Don't find an option like you describe it, see [this screenshot of the Growl options](https://img.skitch.com/20121001-1kqt2gbq6nxspdskkn2qapihwr.png).

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim - I seem to have additional options in the same Guard Notification settings tab - failed, notify, pending and success are listed, and can be configured, separately. Which version of Growl are you using and are you using the `gntp` gem?

Comment: I'm using the App Store version, and no, I use the `growl` gem, not `gntp`, but some time ago I used `gntp`, but I don't remember seeing any additional options back then.

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim if you look at the guard documentation at https://github.com/guard/guard the gntp gem provides multiple channels while the growl gem does not. You need gntp to get the detailed config options.

Comment: I confirmed that I can choose failed, notify, pending, success options using the latest version of Growl from the app store and the ruby_gntp gem.